# Чтобы кнопка выглядела одинаково на всех размерах экранов

Tags: java, android, xml

Как создать кнопку которая будет выглядеть одинаково пропорционально относительно  всех размеров экранов?

Comment: Если вы сходите в какой-нибудь гугель, то там будет несколько десятков страниц, где все подробно объясняется.

Comment: используйте dp в качестве единиц измерения

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko А что означают эти dp

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko вроде как ширина и высота в dp не одинакова для девайсов, так что dp не получится использовать, чтобы всё выглядело одинаково.

Comment: @danchik202020 тут не учат программированию, тут решают конкретные проблемы. погуглите

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko дак я гуглил guidline не подходит потому что он измеряет относительно layout

Comment: @Maxgmer https://startandroid.ru/ru/11-pamjatka/40-edinitsy-izmerenija-chem-otlichaetsja-dp-dip-ot-px-screen-density.html

Comment: @danchik202020 https://startandroid.ru/ru/11-pamjatka/40-edinitsy-izmerenija-chem-otlichaetsja-dp-dip-ot-px-screen-density.html

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko видимо ошибка, можете сами загуглить, какое разрешение в dp у девайсов. Если бы оно было одинаково, можно было бы найти, а так просто список девайсов покажет и их разрешения в dp. DP - удобно, но не панацея.

Comment: @Maxgmer понятно что это не панацея. DP это соотношение пикселей к расширению. Что б идеально было существуют qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов (возможно не самый лучший):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:text="My Button"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Кнопка всегда будет занимать 60% ширины посередине, при условии что контейнер будет размещен от края до края.